# Test if a system of linear inequalities has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have a system of linear inequalities $Ax>0$ where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix with $m \ge n$. Is there a simple way to check whether it has a solution?

What if one of the columns of $A$ is parametrized? In a more general case, I have one of the columns of $A(t)$ as $a(t) = tv+w$, where $t \in [0, 1]$. Is there a way to check whether **all** of the systems $$A(t)x>0, t \in [0,1]$$ have a solution?

Edit: Some additional info, $v$ is a multiple of $\vec{1}$ (vector of all ones).

Comment: One can determine whether $\mathrm A \mathrm x \geq \varepsilon 1_m$ is feasible using linear programming.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Could you elaborate?

Comment: Numerically solving the following linear program $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 0\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x \geq \varepsilon 1_m\end{array}$$ should produce a solution or tell you that none exists. Pick a small $\varepsilon > 0$. If $m$ and $n$ are small enough, you could even use quantifier elimination.